# Typing Speed Tracker with Python

Tags: python, pygame

I was following this tutorial on how to make a typing speed calculator using pygame and whenever I run the code everything renders out as it should but when I try clicking on the text field to input some text it just freezes and nothing happens. I tried to search online or watch tutorials but everything came up empty.

```
import sys
import time
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

"""Python Script for a typing speed test game"""
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.h = 720
        self.w = 1280
        self.reset = True
        self.active = False
        self.word = ""
        self.input_text = ""
        self.time_start = 0
        self.total_time = 0
        self.accuracy = "0%"
        self.wpm = 0
        self.results = "Speed(WPM):0 Accuracy:0% Time:0"
        self.end = False
        self.head_col = (255,213,102)
        self.text_col = (255,255,255)
        self.result_color = (53,209,29)

        pygame.init()
        self.open_image = pygame.image.load("splash.jpg")
        self.open_image = pygame.transform.scale(self.open_image, (self.w,self.h))

        self.background = pygame.image.load("background.jpg")
        self.background = pygame.transform.scale(self.background, (self.w, self.h))
    
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.w,self.h))  
        pygame.display.set_caption = "Type Speed Test"

    def draw_text(self, screen, msg, y, fsize, color):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("consolas", fsize)
        text = font.render(msg, 1, color)
        text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(self.w/2, y))
        screen.blit(text, text_rect)
        pygame.display.update()

    def get_sentences(self):
        f = open("sentences.txt").read()
        sentence = f.split("\n")
        sentences = random.choice(sentence)
        return sentences

    def show_results(self, screen):
        if(not self.end):
            #Calculate Time
            self.total_time = time.Time() - self.time_start

            #Calcualte Accuracy
            count = 0
            for i,c in enumarate(self.word):
               try:
                    if self.input_text[i] == c:
                        count  += 1
               except:
                    pass

            self.accuracy = count/len(self.word)*100

            #Calculate wpm
            self.wpm = len(self.input_text)*60/(5*self.total_time)
             self.end = True
            print(self.total_time)

            self.results = "Time:" + str(round(self.total_time))  
            + " secs Accuracy: " + str(round(self.accuracy)) + "%" 
            + " WPM: " + str(round(self.wpm))
            
            #restart icon
            self.time_img = pygame.image.load("icon.png")
            self.time_img = pygame.transform.scale(self.time_img, (80,320))
            #screen.blit(self.time_img, (80,320))
            screen.blit(self.time_img, (self.w/2-75, self.h-140))
            self.draw_text(screen, "Reset", self/h - 70, 26, (100,100,100))

            print(self.results)
            pygame.display.update()

    def run(self):
        self.reset_game()

        self.running=True
        while(self.running):
            clock = pygame.time.Clock()
            self.screen.fill((0,0,0), (50,250,650,50))
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen,self.head_col, (50,250,650,50), 2)
            # update the text of user input
            self.draw_text(self.screen, self.input_text, 274, 26,(250,250,250))
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    self.running = False
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    # position of input box
                    if(x>=50 and x<=650 and y>=250 and y<=300):
                        self.active = True
                        self.input_text = ''
                        self.time_start = time.time()
                    # position of reset box
                    if(x>=310 and x<=510 and y>=390 and self.end):
                        self.reset_game()
                        x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if self.active and not self.end:
                            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                                print(self.input_text)
                                self.show_results(self.screen)
                                print(self.results)
                                self.draw_text(self.screen, self.results,350, 28, self.RESULT_C)
                                self.end = True
                            elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                                self.input_text = self.input_text[:-1]
                            else:
                                try:
                                    self.input_text += event.unicode
                                except:
                                    pass
            pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)            

    def reset_game(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.open_image, (0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.reset=False
        self.end = False
        self.input_text=''
        self.word = ''
        self.time_start = 0
        self.total_time = 0
        self.wpm = 0
        # Get random sentence
        self.word = self.get_sentences()
        if (not self.word): self.reset_game()
        #drawing heading
        self.screen.fill((0,0,0))
        self.screen.blit(self.background,(0,0))
        msg = "Typing Speed Test"
        self.draw_text(self.screen, msg,80, 80,self.head_col)
        # draw the rectangle for input box
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen,(255,192,25), (50,250,650,50), 2)
        # draw the sentence string
        self.draw_text(self.screen, self.word,200, 28,self.text_col)
    
        pygame.display.update()

Game().run()
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your never handeling KEYDOWN Events. because the else if statement is indented to far.

You should change the following.

```
class Game(object):
    ...
    def run(self):
        ...
        while(self.running):
            ...
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    ...
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    ...
                    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        ...
```

in to this:

```
class Game(object):
    ...
    def run(self):
        ...
        while(self.running):
            ...
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    ...
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    ...
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    ...
```

Comment: Thanks i can now fix it!

Answer (score 0):

In Game.reset_game you recusively call Game.reset_game() with no exit.

Remove the call to self.reset_game so the game can be reset.

---

You also sleep for 1 second in reset_game without listening to events. This will make the pygame window seem inresponsive.

And it lets the process take 1000 seconds or ~ 17 minutes before the RecursionError is triggerd from recursively calling reset_game. Rather then seconds.

Comment: Appologies, i noticed these problems without looking to your actual problem. these two problems are minor issues in your current application and can become a bigger issue later. see my new answer to solve your current problem.